# Show message if all textfields are complete, correctly in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am creating a email input and a name input, and I need to show a message when all fields are complete. But for some reason, when empty fields are there and the user clicks on the submit button, the success message shows instead. Is there way to put in a clause or something to fire it after all fields are completed? thanks for the help.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class RequestFilterVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTxtField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var filterTxtField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var requestBtn: UIButton!        
    @IBOutlet weak var validatorMessage: UILabel!        
    @IBOutlet weak var requestedMessage: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // hide validator message
        validatorMessage.isHidden = true            
        requestedMessage.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBAction func requestBtnWasTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let providedEmailAddress = emailTxtField.text

        let isEmailAddressValid = isValidEmailAddress(emailAddressString: providedEmailAddress!)

        if isEmailAddressValid
        {
            print("Email address is valid")
        } else {
            print("Email address is not valid")
            displayAlertMessage(messageToDisplay: "Email address is not valid")
        }

        // If All are completed then send the email .
        let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self as? MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

        // Configure the fields of the interface.
        composeVC.setToRecipients(["myemail@awesomeemail.com])
        composeVC.setSubject("Form Submit)
        composeVC.setMessageBody("\(emailTxtField, filterTxtField)", isHTML: false)

        // Present the view controller modally
        //  self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        requestedMessage.isHidden = false
        requestedMessage.text = "Submitted form . thank you"            
   }

    func isValidEmailAddress(emailAddressString: String) -> Bool {

        var returnValue = true
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z.-_]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}"

        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: emailRegEx)
            let nsString = emailAddressString as NSString
            let results = regex.matches(in: emailAddressString, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))

            if results.count == 0
            {
                returnValue = false
            }                
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            returnValue = false
        }

        return  returnValue
    }        

    func displayAlertMessage(messageToDisplay: String)
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: .alert)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

            print("Ok button tapped");                
        }

        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
    }    
}
```

Comment: You aren't checking if the second text field is not empty anywhere? Shouldn't you be checking that with the user validation in `requestBtnWasTapped`?

Comment: yeah - I know that. But, I want to get this working when user just types and fills up both fields and then shows the message. Validation I will worry later at this moment

Comment: Where are you checking if **both** fields are filled up? Where are you supposed to check it? In `requestBtnTapped`?

Comment: Also you are supposed to show the message only when the button is tapped right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not **check**ing if the **second text field is empty** or not anywhere. ( I have no clue why you have named a text field that is supposed to store a name is named as `filterTextField` )

```
if isEmailAddressValid && !filterTextField.text?.isEmpty {
    print("Email address is valid")
} else {
    print("Email address is not valid")
    displayAlertMessage(messageToDisplay: "Email address is not valid")
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How does it sound create a delegate with a regex? each time you press a key call the delegate and if it matches the regex you could unhide a UILabel... something like this could work.

Comment: So, you're saying inside `isValidEmailAddress` function I just do `requestedMessage.isHidden = false`  ?

Comment: If you wanna do it tapping your button yes that could work, if not you will need to create a delegate for the textfield and call it every time and check:
 none of the fields are empty and regex matches the emails field. 
BTW try to avoid force unwraps for your safety :)

Comment: Sorry I was in the phone, typing haha the answer right is what I was trying to explain, not empty and regex true :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
displayAlertMessage(messageToDisplay: "Email address is not valid")
```

To

```
displayAlertMessage(messageToDisplay: "Email address is not valid")
return
```

Answer (score 0):

For your problem the following change will handle the error 
After you validate the email you are not returning or braking the flow and it will execute the remaining coed left in your function. So you need to stop the execution.

```
if isEmailAddressValid
        {
            print("Email address is valid")
        } else {
            print("Email address is not valid")
            displayAlertMessage(messageToDisplay: "Email address is not valid")
        }
```

> How ever for better approach, I would suggest to disable the submit 
>   button until the text field has value.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {    //delegate method
   //check for the required text field  
   if (emailTxtField.text!.isEmpty){
      //disable submit button
    }
   else{
     // enable the submit button
     }
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {  //delegate method
   if (emailTxtField.text!.isEmpty){
      //disable submit button
    }
   else{
     // enable the submit button
     }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Great. I will take you're advice. Thanks!